# On click listener in Slider Intro layouts

Tags: java, android, xml, onclicklistener, buttonclick

Actually I am building slider intro for my app . It consists of 3 slide layout (ex: slide1.xml,slide2.xml,slide3.xml), I have button in slide2.xml . Now how to set on click listener for that button.

Comment: try using libraries, that will make your flow very easy.          
`compile 'com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.2'``

Comment: Thanks , I think if nothing goes right ,then this will help me though !

Comment: if u want to get help on your code then u need to post your code here and let us know at what point u r actually stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you used to do the intro, fragment with viewpager?

Watch this:
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/

Comment: That's the tutorial I have used to build my intro, I need to set on click listener for one button in one of that intro layouts.